# Math operation with values from userform's textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a solution to do math operations from six values entered from the left column. (photo)

I have tried both solutions that I found on web :
the 1st one is Application.Evaluate("TextBox2.Value - TextBox4.Value")
the 2nd one is CStr(CDbl(TextBox2.Text) - CDbl(TextBox3.Text))
but they returned either 0 or the excel doesn’t recognize my formula...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

My code was as below

```
Dim ajout As Long
Dim NiveauTN As Long
ajout = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Rows(ajout).Insert 'insertion d'une ligne juste en dessous du tableau
Range("A" & ajout).Value = TextBox1.Value
Range("A" & ajout).Offset(0, 1).Value = TextBox2.Value
Range("A" & ajout).Offset(0, 2).Value = Application.Evaluate("TextBox2.Value-TextBox3.Value")
'Range("A" & ajout).Offset(0, 2).Value = CStr(CDbl(TextBox2.Text) - CDbl(TextBox3.Text))
'Range("A" & ajout).Offset(0, 3).Value = Application.Evaluate("TextBox2.Value - TextBox4.Value")
'Range("A" & ajout).Offset(0, 4).Value = Application.Evaluate("TextBox2.Value - TextBox5.Value")
'Range("A" & ajout).Offset(0, 5).Value = TextBox2.Value - TextBox6.Value
'Range("A" & ajout).Offset(0, 6).Value = TextBox2.Value - TextBox7.Value
'Range("A" & ajout).Offset(0, 7).Value = TextBox2.Value - TextBox8.Value
```

Comment: Please post your code so we know if there's something wrong with how you made the formula or if there's a different issue at hand.

Comment: I wanted to post a photo but they didnt let me to because my account have just signed up for few hours.... sorry

Comment: Try `= Application.Evaluate(TextBox2.Value & "-" & TextBox3.Value)`